# Google chart create

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I need to make, a chart like this, it's a google chart but it's takes values from a spreadsheet online, and i need to give local values.
I tried everything, but nothing work. 
Knows somebody something for this ?
[image]

```
 <html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['table', 'map', 'corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

      function initialize() {
        // The URL of the spreadsheet to source data from.
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(
            'https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pCQbetd-CptF0r8qmCOlZGg');
        query.send(draw);
      }

      function draw(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          alert('Error in query');
        }

        var ticketsData = response.getDataTable();
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
            document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(ticketsData, {'isStacked': true, 'legend': 'bottom',
            'vAxis': {'title': 'Number of tickets'}});

        var geoData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Lat', 'Lon', 'Name', 'Food?'],
          [51.5072, -0.1275, 'Cinematics London', true],
          [48.8567, 2.3508, 'Cinematics Paris', true],
          [55.7500, 37.6167, 'Cinematics Moscow', false]]);

        var geoView = new google.visualization.DataView(geoData);
        geoView.setColumns([0, 1]);

        var table =
            new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(geoData, {showRowNumber: false});

        var map =
            new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));
        map.draw(geoView, {showTip: true});

        // Set a 'select' event listener for the table.
        // When the table is selected, we set the selection on the map.
        google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select',
            function() {
              map.setSelection(table.getSelection());
            });

        // Set a 'select' event listener for the map.
        // When the map is selected, we set the selection on the table.
        google.visualization.events.addListener(map, 'select',
            function() {
              table.setSelection(map.getSelection());
            });
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table align="center">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td style="width: 50%;">
          <div id="map_div" style="width: 400px; height: 300;"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 50%;">
          <div id="table_div"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colSpan=2>
          <div id="chart_div" style="align: center; width: 700px; height: 300px;"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make a chart from what? What is this code? Where does it fail?

Comment: I nned to make a chart with data from a database, and not from a spreadsheet like that code from google charts.

Answer (score 0):

I use a barchart like this.

Connect to the database and make a query:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
  die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = <<<SQL
  SELECT *
  FROM `log`
  WHERE `type` = 'order'
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
```

In my case I have a timestamp and I use that make different arrays to use for different charts.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $orders_year_month_day[date('Y', $row['timestamp'])][date('n', $row['timestamp'])][date('j', $row['timestamp'])][] = $row['wid'];
  $orders_hour[date('G', $row['timestamp'])][] = $row['wid'];
  if (date('Y-n-d', $row['timestamp']) == date('Y-n-d')) {
    $orders_hour_today[date('G', $row['timestamp'])][] = $row['wid'];
  }
  $orders_hour_month[date('G', $row['timestamp'])][date('n', $row['timestamp'])][] = $row['wid'];     
}
```

The above 3 arrays produce the follwing:

```
$orders_year_month_day

Array
(
    [2015] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [20] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 12:11:13
                            [1] => 12:14:51
                            [2] => 12:39:44
                            [3] => 13:03:49
                            [4] => 13:10:15

$orders_hour

Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:11:13
            [1] => 12:14:51
            [2] => 12:39:44
            [3] => 12:44:22

$orders_hour_month

Array
(
    [12] => Array
        (
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12:11:13
                    [1] => 12:14:51
                    [2] => 12:39:44
                    [3] => 12:44:22
                    [4] => 12:49:24
```

I then make one more pass at the above arrays to get the data neede for 3 charts

```
// Total signups today per hour.
if (!empty($orders_hour_today)) {
  foreach ($orders_hour_today as $hour => $signups) {
    $orders_hour_today_total[$hour] = count($signups);
  }
  ksort($orders_hour_today_total);
}

// Total signups across all months per hour.
foreach ($orders_hour as $hour => $signups) {
  $orders_hour_total[$hour] = count($signups);
}
ksort($orders_hour_total);

// Total signups in a month per day.
foreach ($orders_year_month_day[$show_year] as $month => $days) {
  foreach ($days as $day => $orders) {
    $orders_per_day_in_month[$month][$day] = count($orders);
  }
}

// Total signpus for each month per hour.
foreach ($orders_hour_month as $hour => $months) {
  foreach ($months as $month => $signups) {
    $order_hour_month_total[$hour][$month] = count($signups);
    $order_hour_this_month_total[$hour][date('n')] = count($signups);
  }
}
ksort($order_hour_month_total);
```

And then I create the data lists for the charts:

```
$data_add_rows = '';
$data_add_rows_days = '';
$data_add_rows_hour = '';
$data_add_rows_hour_today = '';

foreach ($orders_per_day_in_month as $month => $days) {
  $orders_counted_per_month[$month] = array_sum($days);
  $data_add_rows .= '["' . $month . '", ' . $orders_counted_per_month[$month] . ', ' . $orders_counted_per_month[$month] . "],";
  if ($month == $show_month) {
    foreach ($days as $day => $number_of_signups) {
      $data_add_rows_days .= '["' . $day . '", ' . $number_of_signups . ', ' . $number_of_signups . "],";
    }
  }
}
foreach ($orders_hour_total as $hour => $signups_total) {
  $data_add_rows_hour .= '["' . $hour . '", ' . $signups_total . ', ' . $signups_total . "],";
}
if (!empty($orders_hour_today_total)) {
  foreach ($orders_hour_today_total as $hour => $signups_total) {
    $data_add_rows_hour_today .= '["' . $hour . '", ' . $signups_total . ', ' . $signups_total . "],";
  }
  $data_add_rows_hour_today = rtrim($data_add_rows_hour_today, ",");
} else {
  $data_add_rows_hour_today = '[0, 0, 0]';
}
$data_add_rows = rtrim($data_add_rows, ",");
$data_add_rows_days = rtrim($data_add_rows_days, ",");
$data_add_rows_hour = rtrim($data_add_rows_hour, ",");
```

It will give this

```
// $data_add_rows
["5", 169, 169],["6", 549, 549],["7", 392, 392],["8", 513, 513],["9", 482, 482]
```

And I then have markup like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

  function drawBasic() {

    // Month
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Signups 2015', { role: 'annotation' }],
      <?php print $data_add_rows; ?>
    ]);
    var options = {
      title: 'Website Signups / <?php print $total_signups; ?>',
      chartArea: {width: '50%'},
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Total signups for month',
        minValue: 0
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Month'
      },
      height: 600
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```